# Magento2 UI grid same column problem

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, pagination, ui-grid

I have a problem with pagination in UI Component data grid of Magento2.
[image] 
First time it loads page correctly and pagination works. But on clicking "back" button in paginator all rows change their original content and become copies of the same one row! Pagination direction does not matter, FIRST TIME it paginates correctly in both directions. The problem is only when visiting paginated data AGAIN.

Here is a link to code sample on GitHub: 
https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-sample-module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.xml` at

> view/adminhtml/ui_component/mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.xml

Now replace `<item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
    </item>` at line number 42 as per your code

**Replace**

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
    </item>
</argument>
```

**To**

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        <item name="update_url" path="mui/index/render" xsi:type="url"/>
        <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">index_id</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

**Note: Replace `index_id` to your index field (Main Primary Field)**

Now flush the cache and try.